# affdex VideoDetector failed to open a mp4 file

Tags: affdex-sdk

I'm new to the library and I'm writing a program to analyze videos following the tutorial. Here is my code snippet:

```
        detector = new VideoDetector(24);
        detector.setClassifierPath(classifierPath);
        detector.setImageListener(this);

        detector.setDetectAllExpressions(true);
        detector.setDetectAllEmotions(true);
        detector.setDetectAllEmojis(true);
        detector.setDetectAllAppearances(true);
        detector.setDetectAge(true);
        detector.setDetectEthnicity(true);
        detector.start();
        detector.process("path to the video file");
```

I got the following exception:

Error opening video file: 
Source: __cdecl FileVideoCapture::FileVideoCapture(const class boost::filesystem::path &,const float)(C:\Jenkins\workspace\affdexface-win64\src\modules\utils\FileVideoCapture.cpp LINE 12)

I'm not sure where does the "C:\Jenkins\workspace\" part come from?  Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: The "Jenkins" part in the error is just referring to a source file location in a Jenkins CI build server.

What format of video file are you using?  Is it one for the supported formats listed at http://developer.affectiva.com/supportedvideoformats/? Can you confirm that it's playable using a video player program?

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that you said it was an mp4 file in the title of your question... missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste more information on the codec of the video file. Here are couple of [ways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45927/how-to-find-out-what-codec-is-being-used-in-a-video) in which you can find the codec information.

Can you verify the version of opencv_ffmpeg*.dll? In the SDK installer under Affectiva->AffdexSDK->bin we include either opencv_ffmpeg248 or opencv_ffmpeg248_64.dll based on x86 or x64. Can you verify that you are getting the error using the dll that is shipped?

Did you convert the video to a different file format using [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) and then re-run the application?

Comment: I have opencv_ffmpeg248_64.dll.  The codec of my video file looks like this:  Stream 0: Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1), Resolution: 1280*738, Display resolution 1280*720, Frame rate 24, Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0  YUV full scale.  Stream 1  Type: Audio.  Codec: MPEG AAC Audio(mp4a), Channels: Stereo, sample rate: 48kHz

Comment: @flyhigher did you try the second suggestion of converting to a different format and re-run the application.

Comment: Do you have the `opencv_ffmpeg248_64.dll`  loaded during runtime? We require opencv_ffmpeg*.dll for video decoding during runtime. You will require to copy the dll into either Debug/Release folder based on your configuration.

Comment: Ok I added the dll to the Debug and Release folder. Now the app crashed with the following system events: Fault offset: 0x00000000000b136d
Faulting process id: 0x3060
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2406b5d7f210c
Faulting application path: C:\github\VideoAnalysis\VideoAnalysis\bin\Debug\VideoAnalysis.vshost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\github\VideoAnalysis\VideoAnalysis\bin\Debug\affdex-native.dll

Comment: I tried to use the Kairo sdk to analyze the video and it worked fine. So there must be something wrong with affdex dlls.

Comment: @flyhigher can you send over the video to us so that we can evaluate if it is a problem with the video or with the compilation.